# Resource Leak issue in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-strictmode

My android application is crashing with strictmode violation message with any specific information that what is causing the issue. Crash starting appearing when I configured FCM with my application and I am not performing network operations with FCM right now. I just configured it and crash started to appear.

App is very big and I cannot check all API calls one by one.

Here is the stack trace

```
E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                   java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                       at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
                                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:111)
                                                                       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:300)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
                                                                       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
                                                                       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatw.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatu$4.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzato$zzd.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me debug the issue or point me in a direction that can give me a bit specific answer about it.

Comment: It says that a resource was acquired but never released. Could it be that your operation dies due to activity lifecycle and it does not arrive at the point of releasing the resource? Assuming you release the resource at the end of the operation

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a resource leak, and seems to be exactly the same as in this bug report:     [Google GMS bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229676&can=1&q=-has%3Ahost%20triaged%3Dyes%20attachments%3D0%20label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=4500). I suggest you follow up there.